# Не пингуется машина

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

У меня есть две виртуальных машины(virtual box) на убунту, у них стоит настройка Виртуальный адаптер хоста. Также есть отдельный ноутбук с убунту. Пингуются машины между собой, машины пингуют ноут, но ноут не пингует машины.
Мне нужно передать ssh ключи на машины, но похоже что ноут их не видит. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: пожалуйста, нажав [edit], приведите вывод `$ ip a; ip r` на всех четырёх машинах. и команды, которые вы выполняете. всё, конечно, текстом, не картинкой.

Comment: А есть принципиальная разница как настроена сеть или тебе главное, чтобы работало?

Comment: Как я понял проблема заключалась в том, что у меня виртуальные машины созданы на одном ноутбуке и когда я с другого ноутбука пытаюсь их найти в сети по айпи, то у роутера нет информации о них. Поэтому не пингуется. Поэтому нужно пробросить порты и пинговаться по конкретному порту.